# Sql query find all rows where value is null but another row wih same value not null (Mariadb)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mariadb

```
id_product|pn|ean13|supplier|
-----------------------------
1 |1F46G| FGH45642346|1|
2 |8BBBB| null |1|
3 |1F46G| null |2|
4 |1F46G| FGH45642346 |3|
```

Hello I have table structure like this (just more rows).

I want select all rows where ean13 is null but exists some row where is same PN but ean13 is not null.

```
SELECT id_product,pn
                FROM product
                WHERE pn !='' AND (ean13 is null OR ean13 = '')
                GROUP BY pn
                HAVING count(pn)>1
```

This Select partly working but shows rows where not exists next row with ean13 which is not null

I tried use function exists but the duration is really long time.

Comment: `null` and `''` are not the same. Your code contains both. Also, do you want only the `pn`s in the results or full rows? Clarify what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the query as below to get the desired output.
Write a subquery to identify pn having ean13 as not null.

```
SELECT id_product,pn
from product
WHERE pn !='' AND (ean13 is null OR ean13 = '')
and pn in(
select pn from product where not (ean13 is null OR ean13 = '')
);
```

DB Fiddle: [Result](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=36b38a795356fbe362da4558ac208a3f)

Answer (score 2):

A query based on your precise description *select all rows where ean13 is null but exists some row where is same PN but ean13 is not null* would look like the following. There's nothing that would indicate any aggregation.

I don't know what you mean by *I tried use function exists* since you have not included this.

```
select id_product, pn
from product p
where ean13 is null
  and exists (
    select * from product p2 where p2.pn = p.pn and p2.ean is not null
);
```